# Vlan tagged socket communication for embedded Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, embedded

I have a TCP based server application on Linux that uses AF_INET socket. I would like to tag all outgoing frames with a specific Vlan ID say 10. I tried the following:

1. creating a virtual interface eth0.10 and assigned it an IP address 192.168.0.1. I used the IP address to bind the socket using bind().
2. Binding the socket to the interface eth0.10 using setsockopt().

Even after trying the above ways, I was unable to see any vlan tagged tagged frames or frames with ethtype 0x8100 on wireshark.

Kindly suggest on how to tag packets without using raw sockets.

Comment: How did you create `eth0.10` and what distributive do you use?

Comment: Good code sample at [Vlan id is set to 0 when TPACKET_V2 is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14288582/608639). It looks like `ioctl` and `SIOCSIFFLAGS` is used, which leads to [ioctl "SIOCSIFFLAGS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ioctl+"SIOCSIFFLAGS").